# French Œ not coming through

Tags: flash, special-characters

I have followed [Kostas Zotos instructions over at this forum](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=768105) to see how I can get the Œ to pull into Flash which it is just refusing to do.

My basic example worked but when I try and implement this in a site we have taken over to help a client, the French character Œ just does not want to come through at all.

Things I have done:

- Made sure XML is saved as UTF-8
- XML uses CDATA
- Have embedded fonts
- Have embedded Œ specifically
- Have used another font altogether
- Have placed the character Œ in another text field outside of the MC it's meant to be in and set that as static text which works.
- Have recreated the text field thinking it may have corrupted somehow.
- Have put another text field next to it outside of the mask, changed the name and added the characters to the text field.

Is there anything else I could try that I might be missing?

- I have now also plugged Kostas Zotos' example in directly into the site I am working on and his sample works which leads me to believe there might be something wrong with the XML.
- Could a malformed XML be the cause of something like this? All other special characters are coming through expect for this sucker.
- I have also created an entirely new XML file, saved it as UTF-8 and now the French side of the site wont load.
- I have now also checked and ensured that the XML is not malformed using Firefox and it all looks good.

In the attached example, the blue circle between the --- ---- is where my characters should be appearing which is happening in the text field to the left.

[image]

There's got to be something simlple solution to this but I think that solution is somewhere in the grey patch developing in my right eyebrow!

Answer (score 1):

Does your XML have the proper declaration? I.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ...` Saving as UTF-8 isn't enough; you also must state that it's UTF-8 so the XML parser knows what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify the exact problem you're having:
Do you load the character from the XML correctly (you can verify this easily with traces)? If the problem is on the loading of the XML, you need to guarantee it's being loaded as UTF; if the problem is on the display of the character, you need to make sure you're embedding the font correctly.

Make sure you're embedding the required character for the required font in the required settings (bold, italic, etc) as each one of these settings require a new embedding.

**EDIT:**

To make sure you don't have an embedding problem, transform that textfield that says "Some special characters" in a dynamic text field, only dynamic textfields require embedding, static ones get transformed on compilation.

**EDIT2:**

With the following, your embedding issues should be gone:

In my experience, Flash`s font embedding has always been a little tricky. The way I embed my fonts are as follows:

- Create a dynamic text field on the documents stage outside of the visible area (usually up on the top-left side) for each font and setting (bold, italic, both, etc);
- Click the embed button on each of these created text fields and make sure I select the characters I'm going to use;

That way, since there's a dynamic text field using that font right on the stage, Flash is forced to embed correctly the fonts.